# Implementing assertRaises unittest for class/class method

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have written a class in Python that is intialized with a few arguments.

Iam trying to write a test that check if all the arguments are int, otherwise throw TypeError.

Here is my attempt :

```
import unittest
from footer import Footer

class TestFooter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_validInput(self):
        footer = Footer(4,5,1,0)
        self.assertTrue(footer.validInput())
        #attempt 1:
        footer1 = Footer("four","five",1,0)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, footer1.validInput())
        #attempt 2:
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            Footer("four",5,1,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

However, this will not work. I don't understand why.

Here is the class, I'am writting the test for:

```
class Footer:
    def __init__(self, current_page: int, total_pages: int, boundaries: int, around: int):
        self.current_page = current_page
        self.total_pages = total_pages
        self.boundaries = boundaries
        self.around = around
        try:
            if (self.validInput()):
                footer = self.createFooter()
                self.addEllipsis(footer)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\nError while initializing Footer Class ({e.__class__}).\n Please fix the following: ", e)
        
    def validInput(self) -> bool:
        if (type(self.total_pages) != int or type(self.boundaries) != int or type(self.around) != int or type(self.current_page) != int ):
            raise TypeError("Invalid input. All the arguments must be of type int.")
        if (self.total_pages < 0 or self.boundaries < 0 or self.around < 0 or self.current_page < 0):
            raise ValueError("Invalid values. Please do not provide negative values.")
        if (self.current_page > self.total_pages):
            raise ValueError("Current page must be within the total number of pages")
        return True

    def createFooter(self) -> list:
        footer = []
        for page in range(1, self.total_pages + 1):
            if (page <= self.boundaries):
                footer.append(page)
            elif (page > self.total_pages-self.boundaries):
                footer.append(page)
            elif (page == self.current_page):
                footer.append(page)
            elif ((page > self.current_page and page <= (self.current_page + self.around)) or (page < self.current_page and page >= self.current_page - self.around)):
                footer.append(page)
        return footer

    def addEllipsis(self, footer: list) -> None:
        final_footer = [] 
        i = 0
        for page in footer:
            try :
                final_footer.append(page)
                if(footer[i + 1] - footer[i] > 1):
                    final_footer.append("...")
            except IndexError:
                break
            i += 1
        print("\n", ' '.join(str(page) for page in final_footer))
```

Here is the output for the test :

[image]

Comment: Would you show us what doesn't work, please?

Comment: In python the comments start with `#` usually. Or triple quote. `//` won't work.

Comment: Did you leave both attempts in the code?

Comment: Just a quick guess here, but validInput is called in your constructor, but your constructor is not being assertRaises, so it won't work.

Comment: I added the test output. I think @Michael Robbelard is right, because the TypeError is thrown right away when I initialize the class, before I call the ```validInput()```

Comment: Another problem in the code is that `createFooter` is not defined. Please try an IDE like PyCharm or VSCode (both are free but 1st doesn't need that much configuration). It shows me instantly the problem above :) It also allows you to quickly fix it by selecting the lamp icon.

Comment: There is a bunch of issues in this code, What I said earlier is an issue, but the error is actually being eaten by your try/except block in the constructor that does not reraise the original exception. Looking at what you are trying to accomplish that doesn't seem right. Also Riya's answer below is also correct in that the exception you show in your output is caused by what she found. Also the other commentor is correct about the createFooter. Generally when submitting code to Stack Overflow it is desirable to submit a code chunk that will reporodce the error exactly so that we can test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the **wrong way** to use `assertRaises`:

```
import unittest


def this_func_raises():
    raise ValueError


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, this_func_raises())
```

Note that the ValueError will be raised if you include the `()`, since that would execute `this_func_raises` and the exception will not be caught.

And this is the **right way**:

```
import unittest


def this_func_raises():
    raise ValueError


class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, this_func_raises)
```

---

Note that there are several other problems in your code.
For example this:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    Footer("four", 5, 1, 0)
```

Should be like so:

```
with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
    Footer("four", 5, 1, 0).validInput()
```

---

Lastly, you need to replace `self.createFooter()` with a `pass` until you implement it, or else you'll get another error.

---

This is how your code should look like in order to pass the tests:

```
class Footer:
    def __init__(self, current_page: int, total_pages: int, boundaries: int, around: int):
        self.current_page = current_page
        self.total_pages = total_pages
        self.boundaries = boundaries
        self.around = around
        try:
            if (self.validInput()):
                # self.createFooter()
                pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"\nError while initializing Footer Class ({e.__class__}).\n Please fix the following: ", e)

    def validInput(self) -> bool:
        if (type(self.total_pages) != int or type(self.boundaries) != int or type(self.around) != int or type(
                self.current_page) != int):
            raise TypeError("Invalid input. All the arguments must be of type int.")
        if (self.total_pages < 0 or self.boundaries < 0 or self.around < 0 or self.current_page < 0):
            raise ValueError("Invalid values. Please do not provide negative values.")
        if (self.current_page > self.total_pages):
            raise ValueError("Current page must be within the total number of pages")
        return True
```

test file:

```
import unittest


class TestFooter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_validInput(self):
        footer = Footer(4, 5, 1, 0)
        self.assertTrue(footer.validInput())
        # attempt 1:
        footer1 = Footer("four", "five", 1, 0)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, footer1.validInput)
        # attempt 2:
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            Footer("four", 5, 1, 0).validInput()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```